# change ID columns of every second ID group of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large dataframe with an ID column, the first 8208 rows have ID 1, the next 432 rows have ID 2, the next 8208 rows have ID 3, the next 432 rows have ID 3 etc.

Now I would like to rename the IDs so that the first 432 rows have ID 1.1, the next 432 rows ID 1.2 etc - until 1.19 for rows 7777:8208. Then the next 432 rows remain with ID 2, for the next 8208 the same should be done: ID 2.1, 2.2, etc. until 2.19.

I already tried

```
    split(x, seq(1:19))
```

and then

```
 tapply(df, split)
```

but this changes the order of the rows and obviously does not rename the ID column.
So basically only the odd IDs need to be changed by splitting them in 19 equal parts, keeping row order the same and renaming those parts so that the original ID is added with .1, .2, .3 etc until .19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
df[df$id%%2!=0,"id"]=paste0(df[df$id%%2!=0,"id"],".",rep(rep(seq(1,19),each=432),length(df[df$id%%2!=0,"id"])/8208))
```

I made the assumption that you have multiple of 8208 rows.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not take into account that every second ID only has 432 rows and therefore its ID does not need to be changed. Only the odd ID's need to be split up in 19 equal parts. I have 156 different IDs, but only 78 (half of them) have 8208 rows, the other half has 432 rows, resulting in a total 673920 rows.

Comment: Misunderstanding on my part, I'll try to fix it.

Comment: Edited to only change odd ids.

Comment: Great! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Think this work too, and is a bit easier on the eye. It gives a warning but only because not all values are replaced

```
within(df2, id[df2$id %% 2 != 0] <- paste(id, rep(1:19, 432), sep = '.'))
```